# React Navigation (Stack Navigation Issue) : All the Contents of the screen disappears and a white screen with title on it is shown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I've applied Stack Navigator in React-Navigation for my HomeScreen.

After Applying it I'm getting a totally white screen with title name on top.

Please Help Me Resolve it!

`HomeScreen.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { ScrollView, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Card from "../components/Card";
import { NotificationIcon } from "../components/icons.js";
import Logo from "../components/Logo.js";
import Course from "../components/Course";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
          <Titlebar>
            <Avatar source={require("../assets/avatar.jpg")} />
            <Title>Welcome Back,</Title>
            <Name>Saksham Gupta</Name>
            <NotificationIcon
              style={{ position: "absolute", right: 20, top: 5 }}
            />
          </Titlebar>
          <ScrollView
            style={{
              flexDirection: "row",
              padding: 20,
              paddingLeft: 12,
              marginTop: 30,
            }}
            horizontal={true}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          >
            {logo.map((logo, index) => (
              <Logo key={index} image={logo.image} text={logo.text} />
            ))}
          </ScrollView>
          <Subtitle>Continue Learning</Subtitle>
          <ScrollView
            horizontal={true}
            style={{ paddingBottom: 30 }}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          >
            {cards.map((card, index) => (
              <Card
                key={index}
                title={card.title}
                image={card.image}
                caption={card.caption}
                logo={card.logo}
                subtitle={card.subtitle}
              />
            ))}
          </ScrollView>
          <Subtitle>Popular Courses</Subtitle>
          <ScrollView
            style={{ flexDirection: "row", paddingBottom: 30 }}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          >
            {courses.map((course, index) => (
              <Course
                key={index}
                image={course.image}
                title={course.title}
                subtitle={course.subtitle}
                logo={course.logo}
                author={course.author}
                avatar={course.avatar}
                caption={course.caption}
              />
            ))}
          </ScrollView>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </Container>
  );
}
const Container = styled.View`
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #f0f3f5;
`;

const Title = styled.Text`
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #b8bece;
  font-weight: 500;
`;

const Name = styled.Text`
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #3c4560;
  font-weight: bold;
`;

const Titlebar = styled.View`
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-left: 80px;
`;

const Avatar = styled.Image`
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 22px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
`;

const Subtitle = styled.Text`
  color: #b8bece;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
`;

const logo = [
  {
    image: require("../assets/logo-framerx.png"),
    text: "Framer X",
  },
  {
    image: require("../assets/logo-figma.png"),
    text: "Figma",
  },
  {
    image: require("../assets/logo-studio.png"),
    text: "Studio",
  },
  {
    image: require("../assets/logo-react.png"),
    text: "React",
  },
  {
    image: require("../assets/logo-swift.png"),
    text: "Swift",
  },
  {
    image: require("../assets/logo-sketch.png"),
    text: "Sketch",
  },
];

const cards = [
  {
    title: "React Native for Designers",
    image: require("../assets/background11.jpg"),
    subtitle: "React Native",
    caption: "1 of 12 sections",
    logo: require("../assets/logo-react.png"),
  },
  {
    title: "Styled Components",
    image: require("../assets/background12.jpg"),
    subtitle: "React Native",
    caption: "2 of 12 sections",
    logo: require("../assets/logo-react.png"),
  },
  {
    title: "Props and Icons",
    image: require("../assets/background13.jpg"),
    subtitle: "React Native",
    caption: "3 of 12 sections",
    logo: require("../assets/logo-react.png"),
  },
  {
    title: "Static Data and Loop",
    image: require("../assets/background14.jpg"),
    subtitle: "React Native",
    caption: "4 of 12 sections",
    logo: require("../assets/logo-react.png"),
  },
];

const courses = [
  {
    title: "Prototype in InVision Studio",
    subtitle: "10 sections",
    image: require("../assets/background13.jpg"),
    logo: require("../assets/logo-studio.png"),
    author: "Meng To",
    avatar: require("../assets/avatar.jpg"),
    caption: "Design and interactive prototype",
  },
  {
    title: "React for Designers",
    subtitle: "12 sections",
    image: require("../assets/background11.jpg"),
    logo: require("../assets/logo-react.png"),
    author: "Meng To",
    avatar: require("../assets/avatar.jpg"),
    caption: "Learn to design and code a React site",
  },
  {
    title: "Design and Code with Framer X",
    subtitle: "10 sections",
    image: require("../assets/background14.jpg"),
    logo: require("../assets/logo-framerx.png"),
    author: "Meng To",
    avatar: require("../assets/avatar.jpg"),
    caption: "Create powerful design and code components for your app",
  },
  {
    title: "Design System in Figma",
    subtitle: "10 sections",
    image: require("../assets/background6.jpg"),
    logo: require("../assets/logo-figma.png"),
    author: "Meng To",
    avatar: require("../assets/avatar.jpg"),
    caption:
      "Complete guide to designing a site using a collaborative design tool",
  },
];
```

`AppNavigator.js`

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import SectionScreen from "../screens/SectionScreen";
import HomeScreen from "../screens/HomeScreen";

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
  Section: SectionScreen,
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

`SectionScreen`

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import SectionScreen from "../screens/SectionScreen";
import HomeScreen from "../screens/HomeScreen";

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
  Section: SectionScreen,
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

`App.js`

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import AppNavigator from "./navigator/AppNavigator";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <AppNavigator />
    </Container>
  );
}
const Container = styled.View;
```

I'm New At This, So Please Write Easy Ways to Resolve It.

Here is the screen that is coming up:

[image]

It should have just a navigation header with HomeScreen.js as it main default file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have this?

```js
const Container = styled.View;
```

Remove the `<Container>` from around the `<AppNavigator />` or change it to this:

```js
const Container = styled.View`
  flex: 1;
`;
```